# BeautifulSoup not parsing the entire page content

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the set of url's(which are webpages) from newyork times, but i get a different answer, I am sure that I gave a correct class, though it extracts different classes. My ny_url.txt has "http://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch/?action=click&region=Masthead&pgtype=SectionFront&module=SearchSubmit&contentCollection=us&t=qry900#/isis; http://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch/?action=click&region=Masthead&pgtype=SectionFront&module=SearchSubmit&contentCollection=us&t=qry900#/isis/since1851/allresults/2/"

Here is my code:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
from cookielib import CookieJar
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
text_file = open('ny_url.txt', 'r')
for line in text_file:
    print line
    soup = BeautifulSoup(opener.open(line))
    links = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class' :  'element2'})
    for href in links:
        print href
```

Comment: Iam expecting this result "http://topics.nytimes.com/top/reference/timestopics/organizations/i/isis/index.html?8qa, http://www.nytimes.com/2014/08/25/world/middleeast/isis-militants-capture-air-base-from-syrian-government-forces.html"

Comment: Line probably contains a '\n' character. Try `opener.open(line[:-1])`

Comment: This is the result what i get: after editing according to your suggestion... "http://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch/?action=click&region=Masthead&pgtype=SectionFront&module=SearchSubmit&contentCollection=us&t=qry900#/isis

<div class="resetFilters element2">
<a class="searchFilter" data-refineby="resetFilters">Clear All Filters</a>
</div>
<div class="totalResultsCount element2" id="totalResultsCount">
<p></p>
</div>"

Answer (score 1):

Well its not that simple.

The data you are looking for is not in your page_source downloaded by urllib2.

Try printing the `opener.open(line).read()` you will find the data to be missing.

This is because, the site is making another GET request to `http://query.nytimes.com/svc/cse/v2pp/sitesearch.json?query=isis&page=1`

Where within the url your query parameters are passed `query=isis` and `page=1`

The data fetched is in json format, try opening the url above in the browser manually. You will find your data there.

So a pure pythonic way would be to call this url and parse JSON to get what you want.
No rocket science needed - just parse the dict using proper keys.

OR

An easier way would be to use webdrivers like `Selenium` - navigate to the page - and parse the page source using BeautifulSoup. That should easily fetch the entire Content.

Hope that helps. Let me know if you need more insights.